# WheelCollider messing with CentreOfMass of Vehicle

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

i started using unity 5 and i getting a problem. while changing the centre of mass position, wheel Collider also changing the position.

[image]

first image shows the centre of mass at 0, 0, 0;

[image]

second is centre of mass at 0, 0, 1.53f
in unity 4 i never face this type of problem

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because `CentreOfMass` is a child of `CarWheels`? Try moving `CentreOfMass` so it is not a child and see if that fixes the issue :)